# Commenting on posts Facebook graph api V2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to comment on any post using the id of the post ? I tried with the V2.9 and the comment is successful but when I tried it with V2.10 it shows me the following error

```html
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "B7DlJt0HMOL"
  }
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx46B.png) is what I did in the Graph api Explorer

When I switch the version to V2.9 the comment in the post is successful. Why does this happen or how can I fix it?

Comment: Facebook has deprecated this API call for all versions today due to the end of 90-days grace period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you what the issue is, commenting on everything else than Page posts is deprecated since v2.10 and will not work anymore:

**90-Day Breaking Changes**

> POST and DELETE /{comment-id} — This node now requires a valid page access token.

For more information, take a look at the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.10

Comment: so it is not at all possible (through the api) for a user to post a comment to a post on a page? That seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: exactly, it is not possible. why is this ridiculous? you can just use facebook.com to post a comment, there is no need for an api for this. after all, it can easily be used to spam a page.

Comment: in my use case, it would be very useful: I have a UI where users can post comments, and I want them to be posted on FB as well. What the UI does, it looks up a post on my page, and "spices" it up. I still want all the comments to be available on FB though (that's where I read them from).

Comment: are the documents updated? i can't seem to find those exact words from the documentation

Comment: seems like they changed the changelog and each version got his own page. i will update the answer.

Comment: so what happens now is that, you must use a page access token to comment to its own post?. and user access token can only read comments from its own timeline and no commenting?

Comment: you can only comment as page now

Comment: I don't know why but even after clicking on "get page access token" in the graph API explorer I'm still getting this error "Publishing ... is available for page access tokens". This is a post made by my ID which is visible only to me.

Comment: "visible only to me" - are you sure you are talking about a page and not your user profile?